# l10n support in ruby

Tags: ruby, localization

I am able to parse localized dates using [python locale module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/locale.html) and posix localization database:

```
import locale, datetime

locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME, 'tr_TR.UTF-8')
print datetime.datetime.strptime("1 Haziran 2014", "%d %B %Y")
```

===

Edit

This example loads the locale and datetime modules, parses the localized date to create an instance of python's datetime class. I'm looking specifically for Ruby code that can parse localized dates using posix database.

===

Is there any equivalent of this in ruby? If there is a ruby library like python's locale module or [Boost.Locale](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/locale/doc/html/dates_times_timezones.html) in C++, can you give example code? I tried the [gettext gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/gettext) and [locale gem](http://rubydoc.info/gems/locale/) (I set current locale and tried [Time.strptime](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.2/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-strptime), which failed).

I do not expect to do custom `gsub` or an i18n config file parsing. I am asking for code that uses posix database to parse dates.

Comment: for your python code I get `locale.Error: unsupported locale setting` for the `locale.setlocale` line (for both python 2.7.7 and 3.4.1).

Comment: In addition, as far as I know there isn't a library to do this without parsing an i18n config file. I can give you a lot of different options if you want to do this but there is nothing that is a standard. Does seem silly though, I may create a gem to bundle this stuff...

Comment: @MikeH-R if you want me to diagnose your error, it's because you are trying to use a locale you didn't install. For debian you can do it via `dpkg-reconfigure locales` (install debconf first) see more [here](http://people.debian.org/~schultmc/locales.html)

Comment: Right you are, I didn't realise I needed to have the locale loaded, I just thought I had to have it installed (on arch) checked with one of my locales in the list of `locale -a` and it works perfectly.

Comment: There are many people who can help you with Ruby, but do not know Phyton and its locale module. So I suggest to explain better the result you need.

Comment: @Meier is the clarification sufficient for you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there is currently no ruby gem or code that can load posix database and parse dates using strptime style flags. (copy-paste answer is not accepted)

Answer (score 0):

You will need 2 custom gems in your `Gemfile`

**Chronic:**

```
$ git clone git://github.com/mojombo/chronic.git
$ cd chronic && gem build chronic.gemspec
$ gem install chronic-*.gem
```

**Chronic-l10n:**

```
$ git clone git://github.com/luan/chronic-l10n.git
$ cd chronic-l10n && gem build chronic-l10n.gemspec
$ gem install chronic-l10n-*.gem
```

**Usage:**

```
require 'chronic'
require 'chronic-l10n'

Time.now   #=> Sun Aug 27 23:18:25 PDT 2006

Chronic.locale = :'pt-BR'

Chronic.parse('amanhã')
  #=> Mon Aug 28 12:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('segunda', :context => :past)
  #=> Mon Aug 21 12:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('essa terça 5:00')
  #=> Tue Aug 29 17:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('essa terça 5:00', :ambiguous_time_range => :none)
  #=> Tue Aug 29 05:00:00 PDT 2006

Chronic.parse('27 de maio', :now => Time.local(2000, 1, 1))
  #=> Sat May 27 12:00:00 PDT 2000

Chronic.parse('27 de maio', :guess => false)
  #=> Sun May 27 00:00:00 PDT 2007..Mon May 28 00:00:00 PDT 2007

Chronic.parse('6/4/2012', :endian_precedence => :little)
  #=> Fri Apr 06 00:00:00 PDT 2012
```

Comment: I've seen this. Unfortunately [it loads locales from the library](https://github.com/luan/chronic-l10n/tree/2d9f3e753887216381755f3f2eb8a814113f7760/lib/chronic-l10n) where it stores the configuration files, not posix database.

Comment: @nurettin does it matter if it loads it from the configuration files? for all we know they could have been modelled after the POSIX database. (not saying they are, just that they could be). This does solve the problem.

Comment: @MikeH-R yes, it does matter. I'd have to manage my own copy of posix database then. That is not a solution. The problem is real and neglected by people in the community such as you. (and this gem doesn't even use po or mo files) So no, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Alright, well it looks like it should be simple enough to write a parser for the POSIX data, see files at `ls /usr/share/i18n/locales`. It seems to be a set of values with the unicode symbols encoding them.  You can also read [here for more help](http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/).

Comment: Agree. This is exactly what you wanted.